# How do I add an HTTP header to a web service call?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http-headers

I'm calling a web service from a console app - all in C# on .NET.

I want to add an HTTP header (not a SOAP header) to the web service call. How do I do this?

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
EatService es = new EatService(); // web service added in Web References
// Add HTTP header X-Info = "extra info" here
string info = es.GetMoreInfo(); // ws call
```

Comment: What version of .NET? ASMX web service, or WCF?

Comment: Using .NET 3.5 with an ASMX web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an ASMX web service proxy (Web Reference), then this is a duplicate of [Adding Custom Http Headers to C# Web Service Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309767/adding-custom-http-headers-to-c-web-service-proxy).