# Cant add referance to existing service. HTTP headers required by service

Tags: c#, soap, service, http-headers

I have to use provided Java web service. But the problem is custom HTTPHeaders are required by this service. I have searched for solutions. I think that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310055/1380428) would work if I could add reference. But when I try to add reference to the service I get the following error:

> ```
> There was an error downloading 'http://.....'.
> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://......'.
> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding    the service reference again.
> ```

I think security server doesn't let me access to metadata.
I have tried [this solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) provided at MSDN and added custom headers like below:

```
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://....");
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.

    string postData = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader contentReader = new StreamReader("D:\\test.txt"))
    {
        postData = contentReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Add headers to request
    request.Headers.Add("UserName", "myUserName");
    request.Headers.Add("Password", "myPassword");
    request.Headers.Add("SomeCustomHeader", "myCustomHeaderValue");

    //string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();


    using (StreamWriter resultWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\result.xml"))
    {
        resultWriter.Write(responseFromServer);
    }

    // Display the content.
    //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    Console.ReadLine();
```

and it worked for me. I can get result from service now (as xml files), and I also have WSDL. So I think I can parse this results to appropriate objects. But I want to be able to add service reference and use it like a normal service. I mean calling methods with their names, not using SOAP messages, and getting results as parsed objects.
Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a proxy class using wsdl.exe tool. check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I have created proxy class. Now I will try to use proxy class to connect to server.

Comment: It works very well. Thank you very much. You made my life much more easier )