# How to add token authentication to web services for "Auth-Token"?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, asmx

I'm newer to web services, but I have a web service that I'm consuming/wrapping in Visual Studio C# that ends in `Service.asmx` where I did `Add Service Reference` and it pulled in all of the elements that were showing in `Service.asmx?wsdl`.

It has objects for `Username` and `Password` that worked fine, but now the company who created this web service is changing to token authentication where I get a GUID token and pass null to these elements.

Well shouldn't the web service show a new element where I pass the token?

I'm being told that the token gets passed in the header with field name `Auth-Token`.  So is this something obvious I should do or does the WSDL need updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out more info which may help someone else.  I added the service as a "Service Reference", which is the more advanced WCF, but it's an `asmx` reference which is a "Web Reference".

When you add a service reference, if you click advanced options, there is the older "Web Reference" option which uses .Net 2.0 style.

From there, you just choose your proxy class and override the `System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest` method like this:

```
    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        request.Headers.Add("Auth-Token", this.authToken);
        return request;
    }
```

Comment: This post might help anyone struggling with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310055/71376 - basically the override performed using a partial class.