# Can you alter a web service header in c# program

Tags: c#, web-services, header-files

I currently access a web service, but the "service providers" are altering the requirements and require me to add more information to the header of the request I send them.

My program is written in c# and I have done a lot of research to whether this is even possible, and for the most part have come up blank.

A similar question was asked here: 
[How to add custom Http Header for C# Web Service Client consuming Axis 1.4 Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897782/how-to-add-custom-http-header-for-c-sharp-web-service-client-consuming-axis-1-4) but all this solution did was produce errors I could not solve.

The error is:

```
" 'object' does not contain a definition for 'getWebRequest' "
```

With base.*getWebRequest*(uri);

Comment: Post code. It will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the other question you linked to, the code snippet provided is   `System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);` while your error message refers to `base.getWebRequest`.  Note that the G needs to be capitalized.

If this doesn't help, you need to show us the code that you have which is causing the problem.

Comment: Thats perfect thank you, apologies for the late reply.