# Add x-api-key to request HTTP header using web.config

Tags: c#, wcf

A web service that I'm trying to consume requires that I add **x-api-key** to the HTTP header of the request.
Is it possible to add this new header to the request using the web.config? I've tried to add the **header** element to the endpoint like the example below, but keep getting 403-Forbidden:

```
<endpoint address="webserviceurl"
    behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" binding="customBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="myContract"
    name="serviceName">
    <headers>
      <x-api-key xmlns="webserviceurl">"key"</x-api-key>
    </headers>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964433/how-to-add-a-custom-http-header-to-every-wcf-call

Comment: @DanielA.White both answers regarding web.config is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: perhaps drop the quotes from the value?

Comment: same thing. I think the problem is that it adds to the SOAP headers, not the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to do it through web.config, so I developed a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712795/2526059):

```
WSClient client = new WSClient("endpointName");

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", "key");
    WSRequest req = new WSRequest();
    WSResponse resp = client.WSMethod(req);
}
```